# VC dimension of cone-restricted linear classifiers

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, learning-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a [pointed, salient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone#Blunt.2C_pointed.2C_flat.2C_salient.2C_and_proper_cones) cone in $\mathbb{R}^d$. We may also assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is full-dimensional. Consider the set of binary classifiers $$\mathcal{H} = \{\boldsymbol{x}\mapsto\boldsymbol{1}\hspace{-0.9ex}\mathrm{1}(\boldsymbol{h}^\mathsf{T}\boldsymbol{x}\ge 0)\mid  \boldsymbol{h} \in \mathcal{C} \}.$$
Is there any bound known for the VC-dimension of $\mathcal{H}$ that depends on $\mathcal{C}$ and can be significantly better than the VC-dimension of the set of all (linear) classifiers in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (i.e., $d$)?

**Edit:** Above, $\boldsymbol{1}\hspace{-0.9ex}\mathrm{1}(\cdot)$ denotes the binary indicator function. So a more explicit definition of $\mathcal{H}$ is the set of functions $$f_\boldsymbol{h}(\boldsymbol{x})=\begin{cases} 0  & \text{if }\boldsymbol{h}^\mathsf{T}\boldsymbol{x}<0 \\ 1 & \text{if }\boldsymbol{h}^\mathsf{T}\boldsymbol{x}\ge0\end{cases},$$ parametrized by $\boldsymbol{h}\in \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your notation. What is $\mathcal H$?

Comment: @domotorp I have explained the notation in added edit line. I hope the definition of $\mathcal{H}$ is clear now.

Comment: Thx, now it's clear. I just wonder why you use functions instead of sets, so I would define $S_h=\{x \mid h^Tx\ge 0\}$.

Comment: Also, being pointed or salient doesn't change much, at most a factor of two.

Comment: And there's one more thing missing - what are (linear) classifiers?

Comment: @domotorp Functions and sets are equivalent in this case, but in a broader perspective the VC-theory generalizes two functions that are not necessarily binary-valued.

Comment: The term 'classifier' is often used in statistics and machine learning as I think is used in Vapnik's work. In my example, $f_\boldsymbol{h}(\cdot)$ partitions or ``classifies'' the points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ into two disjoint sets based on linear inequality as the decision rule.

Comment: Regarding the cone being pointed or salient, I intuitively understand your point about the factor of two difference, but I haven't worked out the details rigorously. Are you making a more general statement in the sense that the VC dimension of $\mathcal{H}$ is on the order of $d$ as long as $\mathcal{C}$ is full-dimensional?

Comment: No, I didn't want to make the "more general statement," at least not until now, but I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I claim that the set of $d$ unit vectors, $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, $\ldots,$ $e_d=(0,\ldots,0,1)$, along the axes can be shattered, except that for every $\mathcal H$ either the empty set, or all $d$ of the won't be in any $h\in \mathcal H$, so the VC-dimension is $d-1$. (For similar reasons, it cannot be $d$ for any point set.)

Indeed, if $\mathcal H$ is the *opposite* of the cone spanned by the above $d$ vectors, i.e., the all-negative hyperoctant, and $h_I=-\sum_{i\in I} e_i$, then $f_h(e_i)=0$ if and only if $i\in I$.

Comment: Is this independent of the cone $\mathcal{C}$ (i.e., the domain where $\boldsymbol{h}$ lives in)?

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, you are taking the cone to be the positive (or the negative) orthant. Does it generalize to arbitrary cones?

Comment: Yes, it works the same for any full-dimensional cone, you just have to replace the $e_i$ with other vectors whose negation is in the cone.